# Taxes on PPF Interest Amount

Tags: united-states, india, fbar

Do I have to pay taxes on the PPF (Indian Account) interest amount in USA even though I am not withdrawing or distributing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I have to pay taxes on PPF in USA?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/36246/do-i-have-to-pay-taxes-on-ppf-in-usa)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, PPF and EPF is taxable in US.

other source: [Do I have to pay taxes on PPF in USA?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/36246/do-i-have-to-pay-taxes-on-ppf-in-usa?rq=1)

NOTE: Do not trust people om internet. You yourself will be liable for any wrong information and losses due to that.

Comment: Re: your note on trust, the best way to address this is a link to a reputable source.